# Django - Add Empty Form in Tabular Format

Tags: jquery, python, html, django, python-3.x

I have a template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'selfserve/style.css' %}" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" action="">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ modelformset.management_form }}
    <div id="form_set">
        {{ modelformset.non_form_errors.as_ul }}
        <table id="formset" class="form">
        {% for form in modelformset.forms %}
          {% if forloop.first %}
          <thead><tr>
            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
            <th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
            {% endfor %}
          </tr></thead>
          {% endif %}
          <tr>
          {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
            <td>
            {% if forloop.first %}
              {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
              {{ hidden }}
              {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
              {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
              {{ field }}
            </td>
          {% endfor %}
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="empty_form" style="display:none">
      <table class='no_error'>
        <tr>
          {% for field in modelformset.empty_form %}
          <td>
            {{ field }}
          </td>
          {% endfor %}
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Add" id="add_more">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <script>
        $('#add_more').click(function() {
            var form_idx = $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
            $('#form_set').append($('#empty_form').html().replace(/__prefix__/g, form_idx));
            $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val(parseInt(form_idx) + 1);
        });
    </script>
    {% if messages %}
    <ul class="messages">
        {% for message in messages %}
        <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The template includes an "Add More" button that is run by jQuery. It is based on a model formset that includes some existing data. With this template, the existing data shows up in a nice, tabular format. However, when I click on the "Add More" button, an empty form appears in tabular format...but it is not aligned. I believe the CSS is not being applied to both tables the same way for some reason, and I can't figure out why.

If I put the following inside the empty_form div, the new form appears, but it's obviously not in tabular format:

```
<table class='no_error'>
        {{ modelformset.empty_form.as_table }}
</table>
```

How should I adjust the template so the new form is added appropriately and shows up in aligned, tabular form? Also, is there any way to simplify the logic of the table aspect of this template?

Thank you for any insight you all may have!

**Update:**

I added:

```
<tr>
{% for field in modelformset.empty_form %}
<td>
{{ field }}
<td>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
```

This gets me the correct fields and in tabular format. However, the second field starts at a different point than the existing forms in the formset, so the newly added forms are not aligned properly. For some reason, I don't think the css is being applied to the empty_form table the same way it is to the existing forms.

Comment: Do you remove the ``style="display:none"`` at any point?

Comment: No, not that I'm aware of. Essentially I just replaced the last bit of code in my question with the full table format that's in there now.

Comment: Removing it doesn't alter anything.